# Allow me to reply to myself on chat

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Would make life a bit easier, say for example I want to refer someone to something I once said.

Comment: If you want to refer to something you (or anyone) has said previously, you can simply post the permalink for that message - chat will then one-box the quote, providing the time it was said and links to the permalink, room, etc

Comment: I haven't seen a valid use case for this, ever. @DMA57361 is correct; a quote one box makes a couple thousand percent more sense than "replying to yourself". Even [Michael Mrozek's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/allow-me-to-reply-to-myself-on-chat/82649#82649) trick has never been used for anything but joking.

Comment: @balpha: I just wanted this because I wanted to post a follow-up to something I said in 'chat'.  My previous message had been something like, "There's probably a discussion on this on meta" which I then found, so I wanted to post the link.  But since some time had elapsed, I wanted to connect the two comments to make it clear to others where the thread was.  I'll use Michael's trick in future, but I don't see why this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @balpha: I just wanted to post the same feature request ... It sometimes comes up that I want to refer to an earlier message of mine. This has the advantage of highlighting when hovering over the relevant message. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1600107#1600107 for an example using Michael's hack. (Of course, this does not work in the transcript, where both posts are splitted over two pages.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: If you just *link* to your older message, it will onebox, so it will be *right there* to read, instead of forcing people to  click somewhere. It's called "replying" for a reason. What you're doing isn't replying.

Comment: @balpha: The point is that there is in fact not just one message, but a series of messages - should I quote them all?

Comment: @balpha See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153534/link-to-own-message-in-chat

Comment: @balpha, the conversation threading features in chat are very useful for following a string of linked messages, especially when you want to follow one of a bunch of simultaneous conversations. In particular, when you mouse over a message, the engine highlights messages on the screen if that message replied to them or if they replied to that message. For this purpose, I have replied to my own messages using the workaround, and seen [others](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1754) do the same, many times. I request that you consider again removing unnecessary cumber from this feature.

Answer (score 9):

This is possible, there's just no little arrow for it. If you check the permalink of one of your posts, it will end with the post ID. You can start a new message with `:ID` and it will show up as a reply to that post

Comment: Maybe the request should be *Allow easy reply to self on chat*.

Comment: I just used this to post a message that replied to itself.  It didn't know that it was replying to itself (the arrow didn't show up), but the correct '@AndrewStacey' was applied.  Now I'm going to try a message that replies to one in the future.  Let's see if the future responds...

Answer (score 4):

[This script](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/raw/master/SEChatModifications.user.js) ([howitworks](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts)) allows that. I've checked on Chromium. Real nice. I like the keyboard shortcuts especially. Install it and play with it on [the Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox).