# Link to own message in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow me to reply to myself on chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/allow-me-to-reply-to-myself-on-chat)

I wanted to refer to an own message in chat, but realized, that it is not possible. Think of this situation: You write something, and later you want to add something to this first message, but the grace period for editing is over. When in the meantime others wrote messages, then the context is lost. Now I could add a link in the beginning (the permalink address), but that’s very inconvenient.

*Therefore my request:*
I’d consider it a useful enhancement to provide the ability for linking to own messages.

Edit in reaction to comments:

Want I meant is this small hooked arrow on the right, what I get with a mouseover on a message of another chatter, or when I mouseover on the left side and “reply to this message”.

The part with manual inserting of the ID I didn’t know, but that’s clearly an – again – *in*convenient workaround.

Comment: One way to do that is to [reply to yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82649/149052).

Comment: What @Null says.

Comment: @Pekka stop posting useless "what X said" comments! They add nothing of value to the conversation. Just upvote the original comment.

Comment: @Pekka you don't get to tell me what to do. I'll add my comments wherever I damn well please.

Comment: Every message has a permalink and thus can be linked to, including your own. Can you clarify what you want to add to that?

Comment: @balpha The OP said *Now I could add a link in the beginning (the permalink address), but that’s very unconvenient (sic).*

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ That only tells me what the OP does *not* want to do. I don't understand what they *want instead*. (Okay, I also don't understand the inconvenience, so some clarification on that would be great as well.) Point being: I don't understand what precisely this request is requesting.

Comment: @balpha They just want direct replies to their own message so they can provide some linked clarification after the fact without having to `[clarification on my previous message](#post)`, it sounds like...which would make this a duplicate of that other [meta-tag:status-declined] request.

Comment: @TimStone: I fear you are right with the duplicate _(Note to myself searching for `[chat] +own +message` isn’t enough)._ However I consider my question _slightly_ better substantiated. Why did the other one get the [tag:status-declined] tag? It’s always unsatisfying to get such things without any justification.

Comment: @Speravir Because [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82645/allow-me-to-reply-to-myself-on-chat/82649#comment259894_82645), I assume